# What's the proper way to get a datetime-local value from the input and insert it into a database?

Tags: php, database, datetime, mysqli

I have a form with a datetime-local input and I'm looking for how to extract the value of the date and time that the user has inputted into this datetime-local and pass its value into a column named listDates in my database table called date_table;

My database connection works fine and everything.  And I have more of these similar functions that adds simple strings form textboxes and they all work fine.  It's just the datetime-local that's not registering (or rather only registers it as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (the initial datetime value of January 1, 1970).

How may I properly get the value of datetime-local and pass it into my database?  Thank you for any help you can offer, I'm only stuck with this particular part with coding PHP and MySQLi.

**My Form**

```
     <form>

        <input name="theDate" type="datetime-local" required>

        <a href="dateCRUD.php?theDate=<?php $_GET['theDate'] ?>&action='addDate'"</a>

        <!--I'm not sure if $_GET should be the proper way to get the datetime-local value-->
    </form>
```

**My dateCRUD php where I add, update, delete dates from a database table called date_table**

```
    $theDate = isset($_REQUEST['theDate']);

    switch($_REQUEST['action']){
        case 'addDate':
        {
             addDate($theDate);
             break;
        }
    }
```

**My php MySQLi function to addDate()**

```
      function addDate($theDate)
      {
           global $conn; //my connection to my database which works fine.

           $query = 'INSERT INTO date_table SET listDates = ?';
           $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
           $stmt->bind_param('s', $theDate) //can datetime-local be a 'string'?
           $stmt->execute();
      }
```

**EDIT**

If it helps, I set my listDate type to 'datetime' in my date_table in my database.  Should I change it to 'string' type instead?

Comment: echo out the $theDate value. I am guessing that it is adding the timezone info which the database doesn't understand so sets the value to zero. If you want to keep the timezone info then you may have to extract this info, create another field in the database and store it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your form where you are try to send  datetime-local input to server and store to database. Type datetime of date_table in database is fine. Datetime store  datetime-local value. In your form `<a href="dateCRUD.php?theDate=<?php $_GET['theDate'] ?>&action='addDate'"</a>`, `<?php $_GET['theDate'] ?>` does't send date time local value to server. You should send form value using a button in form. Like as

```
<form method="post" action="dateCRUD.php&action=addDate">
        <input name="theDate" type="datetime-local" required>
        <input type="submit" name="addDate">

</form>
```

**Update your php code as**

```
if(isset($_POST['addDate'])){
 $theDate = isset($_POST['theDate']);
 switch($_REQUEST['action']){
    case 'addDate':
    {
         addDate($theDate);
         break;
    }
 }
}
```

Use the same MySQL function for store date in database.